# Limpiar un Jtable

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

Buenos días compañeros,

Tengo un problema, estoy llenando una tabla desde un jtextfield y en la primera parte funciona perfectamente, cuando se graba en la base de datos y la tabla se limpia y quiero ingresar nuevos datos en la tabla me sale el siguiente error. java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1> = 1 java.lang.NumberFormatException: Para cadena de entrada: "nulo".

si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria.

adjunto el código de donde se alimenta la tabla.

```
private void txt_cantidadKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

        if (!"".equals(txt_cantidad.getText())) {
            Connection con =null;
            try {

                double costo = Double.parseDouble(txt_preciocompra.getText());
                int cantidad = Integer.parseInt(txt_cantidad.getText());
                double iva = Double.parseDouble(txt_impuesto.getText());
                int stock = 0;

                con = getConection();
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT stockinv FROM inventarioalmacen WHERE idmaterialinv=? ");
                ps.setString(1, txt_material.getText());
                ResultSet resultado = ps.executeQuery();

                if (resultado.next()) {
                    stock = resultado.getInt("stockinv");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se encontro el Material");
                    return;
                }

                if (stock != cantidad) {
                    DefaultTableModel temp = (DefaultTableModel) tbl_datos.getModel();
                    temp.addRow(new Object[1]);
                    int columna = 0;
                    tbl_datos.setValueAt(txt_material.getText(), fila, columna);
                    columna++;
                    tbl_datos.setValueAt(txt_descripcion.getText(), fila, columna);
                    columna++;
                    tbl_datos.setValueAt(txt_codbarras.getText(), fila, columna);
                    columna++;
                    tbl_datos.setValueAt(txt_cantidad.getText(), fila, columna);
                    columna++;
                    tbl_datos.setValueAt(txt_almacen.getText(), fila, columna);
                    columna++;
                    tbl_datos.setValueAt(txt_preciocompra.getText(), fila, columna);
                    columna++;
                    double impuesto = ((costo * cantidad)*iva)/100;
                    tbl_datos.setValueAt(impuesto, fila, columna);
                    columna++;
                    double importe = costo * cantidad;
                    tbl_datos.setValueAt(importe, fila, columna);

                    fila++;
                    limpiarcajasmaterial();
                    
                    subTotal();
                    impuestoIva();
                    totalaPagar();
                    txt_material.requestFocusInWindow();

                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Material no existe");
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

y el código con el cual se graba en la base de datos:

```
private void btn_crearActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    Connection con = null; //CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS.
    
    if (fila == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay articulos para el Pedido");
    } else {
            
        try {

            int idVenta = 0;

            con = getConection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO compraspedido (idprovcompraped, nombreprovcompraped, "
                    + "fpedcompraped, fentregacompraped, direccioncompraped, ordencompraped, comentarioscompraped, "
                    + "subtotalcompraped, ivacompraped, totalapagarcompraped, condicionespagocompraped ) "
                    + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            ps.setString(1, txt_proveedor.getText());
            ps.setString(2, txt_nomproveedor.getText());
            SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); // CONVERTIR EL FORMATO A LA FECHA DESEADA.
            ps.setString(3, formato.format(Dtd_fpedido.getDate()));
            ps.setString(4, formato.format(Dtd_fentrega.getDate()));
            ps.setString(5, txt_direccion.getText());
            ps.setString(6, txt_ordencompra.getText());
            ps.setString(7, txt_comentarios.getText());
            ps.setString(8, txt_subtotal.getText());
            ps.setString(9, txt_iva.getText());
            ps.setString(10, txt_totalapagar.getText());
            ps.setString(11, cbo_forma.getSelectedItem().toString());
           
            ps.executeUpdate();

            ResultSet resultado = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
            resultado.next();
            idVenta = resultado.getInt(1);

            if (idVenta == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar el Pedido");
                return;
            }

            agregaProductos(idVenta);
                            
            idpedido();
            limpiarcajas();
            limpiartabla();
            total = 0.00;
            txt_subtotal.setText("0.00");
            txt_iva.setText("0.00");
            txt_totalapagar.setText("0.00");
                          
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pedido Completo");

            txt_proveedor.requestFocus();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

y el código para limpiar la tabla

```
public void limpiartabla(){
    DefaultTableModel temp = (DefaultTableModel) tbl_datos.getModel();
    int filas = tbl_datos.getRowCount();

    for (int a = 0; filas > a; a++) {
        temp.removeRow(0);
    }
}
```